# C++ Error with Templates and deduced conflict types for parameter

Tags: c++, templates, makefile, pointer-to-member, member-functions

Im sitting on this problem for quite a while. The thing is, I want a class that can measure CPU cycles and clock time a functions needs to terminate. 
The problem is i want to give a member function of this class Meter different pointer from functions that have differnent return types and argument types.
(In my case Fibonacci and Sorting Algorithms)
I'm stucked and can't get any further. I hope you can help me.

Meter.h:

```
class Meter
{
Stopwatch w;

const char* filenameTime;
const char* filenameCycle;
const char* filenamePlotTime;
const char* filenamePlotCycle;

vector<uint64_t> t_measures;
vector<uint64_t> c_measures;

uint64_t t_max;
uint64_t t_min;
double t_mean;

uint64_t c_max;
uint64_t c_min;
double c_mean;

double t_standardDeviation;

double c_standardDeviation;

uint32_t numberOfTests;

public:

    //const char* filename;

    Meter(const char* fileData,const char* FileCycle,const char* filePlotCycle,const             char* filePlotTime);

    template<typename RT,typename PT>
    void measure(uint32_t numOfTest, RT(*f)(PT arg),PT valueToTest);

    template<typename RT,typename PT>
    void measureAlgorithmTime(uint32_t numOfTest, RT(*f)(PT arg),PT valueToTest);

    template<typename RT,typename PT>
    void measureAlgorithmCycles(uint32_t numOfTest, RT(*f)(PT arg),PT valueToTest);

    void initfileData();
    void initfileCycle();

    void printDataTime(const char* casename);
    void printDataCycle(const char* casename);
    void printDataToPlotTime(const char* casename,int n);
    void printDataToPlotCycle(const char* casename, int n);
};

template <typename RT, typename PT>
void Meter::measure(uint32_t numOfTest, RT(*f)(PT arg), PT valueToTest)
{
measureAlgorithmTime(numOfTest, (*f),valueToTest);
measureAlgorithmCycles(numOfTest, (*f), valueToTest);
}
template <typename RT, typename PT>
void Meter::measureAlgorithmTime(uint32_t numOfTest, RT(*f)(PT arg), PT valueToTest)
{

if(numOfTest > 0)numberOfTests = numOfTest;

t_measures = vector<uint64_t>(numberOfTests, 0);

//do tests
for(uint64_t i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++)
{
    w.start();
    (*f)(valueToTest);
    w.stop();
    t_measures[i] = w.peek();
    w.reset();
}
/*
compute statistcs
 .
 .
 .
*/
template <typename RT, typename PT>
void Meter::measureAlgorithmCycles(uint32_t numOfTest, RT(*f)(PT arg), PT valueToTest)
{

if(numOfTest > 0) numberOfTests = numOfTest;

//build Memory for Data from Measurements
c_measures = vector<uint64_t>(numberOfTests, 0);



//unsigned long flags;
uint64_t c_start, c_end, c_diff;
unsigned cycles_low, cycles_high, cycles_low1, cycles_high1;
//disable preemption
//preempt_disable();
//disable hard interrupts
//raw_local_irq_save(flags);

for(uint64_t i = 0; i < numberOfTests;i++)
{

    asm volatile
    (
        "CPUID\n\t"
        "RDTSC\n\t"
        "mov %%edx,  %0\n\t"
        "mov %%eax,  %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low):: "%rax", "%rbx",       "%rcx", "%rdx"
    );

    //call function to measure and let it do work
    (*f)(valueToTest);

    asm volatile
    (
        "CPUID\n\t"
        "RDTSC\n\t"
        "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high1), "=r" (cycles_low1):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"
    );
```

main :

```
#include <Meter.h>
#include <Sorting.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char AlgName[20];

cout << "Start to Measure Sorting Algorithms!" <<endl;

uint32_t numberoftest = 10;
int lengthOfTestVector = 10;
vector<int> test;
test.reserve(lengthOfTestVector);
Sorting::addRandomNumbers(test);
Sorting::printOut(test);

cout << "Start to Measure InsertionSort" << endl;

Meter InsertionSort = Meter("InsertionSort_Time","InsertionSort_Cycle",
                            "InsertionSort_Plot_Cycle","InsertionSort_Plot_Time");

for(uint32_t i = 0;i < numberoftest;i++)
{
    InsertionSort.measure(numberoftest,*Sorting::insertionSort<int>,test);
    InsertionSort.printDataTime(AlgName);
    InsertionSort.printDataCycle(AlgName);
    InsertionSort.printDataToPlotCycle(AlgName,i);
    InsertionSort.printDataToPlotTime(AlgName,i);
}

cout << "finished to Measure InsertionSort" << endl;


}
```

the 2 functions i want to give Meter::measure are:

- uint64_t Fibonacci::calculateNthFibonacciNumber(uint32_t n)
  and
- void Sorting::insertionSort(vector &toSort)

i compile this with gcc and my own makefile.

Makefile :

```
#makros
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x -Wall -O -c
FLAGSFOROBJECTS = -o $@
#-I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32/include/asm-generic
CXXFLAGS_GTEST = -I/home/maximilian/gtest-1.7.0/include
CXXFLAGS_INCLUDE = -I/home/maximilian/Documents/AlgorithmEngineering/includes
#LDFLAGS = -L/usr/lib/libgtest.a -pthread
LDFLAGS = /home/maximilian/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.a -pthread
OBJECTS = objects/
MAINS = main/

$(OBJECTS)Sorting.o: src/Sorting.cpp includes/Sorting.h
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS_INCLUDE) src/Sorting.cpp $(FLAGSFOROBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS)Stopwatch.o: test/Stopwatch.cpp includes/Stopwatch.h
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS_INCLUDE) test/Stopwatch.cpp $(FLAGSFOROBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS)Meter.o: test/Meter.cpp includes/Meter.h
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS_INCLUDE) test/Meter.cpp $(FLAGSFOROBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS)Sorting_meter.o: $(MAINS)Sorting_meter.cpp
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS_INCLUDE) $(MAINS)Sorting_meter.cpp $(FLAGSFOROBJECTS)
Sorting_meter: $(OBJECTS)Sorting_meter.o $(OBJECTS)Sorting.o $(OBJECTS)Meter.o       $(OBJECTS)Stopwatch.o
     $(CXX) -o Sorting_meter $(OBJECTS)Sorting_meter.o $(OBJECTS)Sorting.o $(OBJECTS)Meter.o $(OBJECTS)Stopwatch.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

Errors are :

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O -c -I/home/maximilian/Documents/AlgorithmEngineering/includes    main/Sorting_meter.cpp -o objects/Sorting_meter.o
main/Sorting_meter.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main/Sorting_meter.cpp:26:77: error: no matching function for call to       ‘Meter::measure(uint32_t&, void (&)(std::vector<int>&), std::vector<int>&)’
     InsertionSort.measure(numberoftest,*Sorting::insertionSort<int>,test);
                                                                         ^
main/Sorting_meter.cpp:26:77: note: candidate is:
In file included from main/Sorting_meter.cpp:1:0:
/home/maximilian/Documents/AlgorithmEngineering/includes/Meter.h:55:14: note:      template<class RT, class PT> void Meter::measure(uint32_t, RT (*)(PT), PT)
     void measure(uint32_t numOfTest, RT(*f)(PT arg),PT valueToTest);
          ^
/home/maximilian/Documents/AlgorithmEngineering/includes/Meter.h:55:14: note:   template      argument deduction/substitution failed:
main/Sorting_meter.cpp:26:77: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘PT’      (‘std::vector<int>&’ and ‘std::vector<int>’)
     InsertionSort.measure(numberoftest,*Sorting::insertionSort<int>,test);
                                                                         ^
make: *** [objects/Sorting_meter.o] Error 1
```

I tried everything to avoid the errors but now I have no idea and I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename RT, typename PT>
void Meter::measure(uint32_t numOfTest, RT(*f)(PT arg), PT valueToTest)
{
    // […]
}
```

`PT` is deduced from both the second and the third argument. In `main` we've got

```
InsertionSort.measure(numberoftest, *Sorting::insertionSort<int>, test);
```

Note the types of the second and third parameter, respectively:

- `test` will lead to `PT` being deduced as `vector<int>`.
- We can't see the declaration of `Sorting::insertionSort`, but I assume that its taking a `vector<T>&` as its parameter. Thus `PT` will be deduced as `vector<int>&`, which is not what our previous deduction yielded. (The asterisk is presumably unnecessary, as it automatically decays the specialization to a function pointer and subsequently dereferences it)

Solve that by making the third parameter a non-deduced context, or using a second template parameter. E.g.

```
template <typename RT, typename PT, typename PT2>
void Meter::measure(uint32_t numOfTest, RT(*f)(PT arg), PT2 const& valueToTest)
{
    measureAlgorithmTime(numOfTest, (*f),valueToTest);
    measureAlgorithmCycles(numOfTest, (*f), valueToTest);
}
```

Comment: Hey Columbo, thanks for your answer!
Can you explain what you mean by non-deduced context?
I'm fairly new to C++.

Comment: And the Sorting::insertionSort is
   template(typename T)
   void Sorting::InsertionSort(vector<T> &toSort)
   {}

Comment: Pretty much :D

Thanks for your help!